# a way to send multiple tokens with JUST ONE REQUEST to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, laravel-8, amazon-sns, laravel-api

I am developing now AWS-SNS push notification. I want to sent token(endpoint) to AWS side. For this is ok. But for multiple tokens, we have to send requests to AWS multiple times. That's why I want to add for one request, is there a way to create multiple tokens with JUST ONE REQUEST to AWS.

`Here is for one token`

```
$result = $client->createPlatformEndpoint(array(
                'PlatformApplicationArn' => $platformApplicationArn,
                'Token' => $input['token'],
  
            ));

            $endPointArn = isset($result['EndpointArn']) ? $result['EndpointArn'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you are required to make one request per endpoint you wish to add.